# How to find route name for given path in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

When I parse html response body I want to find route names for all links found in the body. I use next code snippet:

```
    my $url =  Mojo::URL->new( $got );
    my $method =  uc( $url->query->clone->param( '_method' ) || 'GET' );
    my $c =  $t->app->build_controller;
    my $m =  Mojolicious::Routes::Match->new( root => $t->app->routes );

    $m->find( $c => { method => $method,  path => $url->path } );
```

Then `$m->endpoint->name` gives me the name of route.

**But is there more simple way to find route name by given path?**

I am looking for something like: `$app->routes->find( '/api/v/users/146/link/7QRgs' )` which should return `user_hash_check` because I have next route:

```
$guest->get( '/users/:id/link/:hash', 'user_hash_check' )->to( 'user#hash_check' );
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, when do you use this? Are your parsing your own application's website?

Comment: @simbabque: Yes, I do. Actually I use this in tests

Comment: Interesting approach. Is simply clicking the links not sufficient?

Comment: What's the problem with the solution you posted? Is it expensive? Or did you just forget you can create a sub?

Comment: @ikegami: I think for this common case the sub should already exists in Mojolicious

Comment: Doesn't sound very common to me!

Comment: @ikegami: Mojolicious when got request it creates route which is accessible as `$c->match`. So somewhere it already converts `path` string into `route` object. Also there [note about reversibility](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Reversibility). To render route into path I can: `$r->lookup( 'route_name' )->render({ foo => 'bar' })`. But I did not find easy way to get route by path, except those five lines of code in question that I should put into sub

Comment: I agree with @ikegami that it's probably enough to just wrap this up in a sub and hide it in the test somewhere. If you want, you can inject it into the namespace of `$t` and make it a method, so you could do your own `$->url_matches_any_route($url)`. It would have to do some basic Test::Builder interaction, but you can easily borrow that from any other testing module, and return `$t`.

Answer (score -1):

I have found only one place where we can find route by path. That is [Mojolicious::Routes::Match](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes::Match#SYNOPSIS) and **there is no other way to do this**

The one ugly thing here to my mind is requirement to supply [Mojolicious::Controller](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Controller) object. But controller is only required to make decision: *dispatch or not dispatch* Because it has extra info to make this decision: this is data to check [conditions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes#conditions)

The problem as I think is because of here are mixed two things:

1. Request
2. Path

And [find](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes::Match#find) should just return all routes matched against given arguments: path and method. Like [selectors does](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) The array result maybe cached (now routes with conditions are not cached)

Then **dispatcher** should check [conditions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes#conditions) against each route, not [matcher](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.14/lib/Mojolicious/Routes/Match.pm#L60). Here each condition may be called *in context of right controller and not default one*. And this will fix [this issue](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/mojo/2015-11-14/text). The routes have in most cases their own controller class have not?

Until this behavior will be fixed **the example in the question is the best way to find routes**